# Data Event / Server Side Event in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Does anyone know how to trigger an event in Google App Maker when something happens on the server side? Such as when new data gets entered in the model, an action happens on the client side? I am using the standard Google MySQL as the database.

Comment: Couple of things to keep straight. Model events are only triggered if the action was called from the client, you can make a call back to the client when the server model event finished by using `widget.datasource.createItem({success: function(record) { console.log(record.id + ' was created'); }, failure: function(error) { console.log(error.message);}});` for example. The same is true for client functions `.deleteItem()` or `.saveChanges()` (however for saveChanges the datasource needs to be manual save).

Comment: If you use `google.script.run` from the client to initiate a server function then you would use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(YourClientSuccessFunction).withFailureHandler(YourClientFailureFunction).YourServerFunction()`. I believe my first comment better suits what you are looking for though based on your question.

Comment: Hi @MarkusMalessa, thanks for that but I should have been more clear on the situation. My app creates a link to open up a custom form on Paperforms, and we use that to enter in more information and submit. This data is then Zapier'ed back into my SQL and I need an action on the client side when that happens. So I need a client side action when an external action happens on the server side and I cannot change any of that process...

Comment: @BobbyS so far data events can only be triggered by client UI interaction or client script, I also think a server side trigger will be useful, so I request a new feature https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139012309